# Seeking solution to resolve merge conflicts

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-merge

so I'm building a tool to allow users modify a file and create a PR. Here it goes:

B is a fork of remote repo A.

Steps:

1. Verify there exists a fork B of A.
2. If exists, try to sync fork B with `merge-upstream` with github API.
3. If there were changes and it was successfully synced, pull new changes to local clone of the repo.
4. make changes to concerned file, commit and push changes back to fork.
5. create a pull request to repo A.

Now fork B is 1 commit ahead of original repo A. Let's assume pull request was not accepted and repo A has made new changes. Now fork B is 1 commit behind to A as well 1 commit ahead of A due to previous case(pull request) and now if we do sync(`merge-upstream`), it wouldn't be possible due to merge conflict.

What I'm looking for is a simple strategy that whenever we sync our fork B it should fetch the latest state of repo A discarding any previous commits that were ahead of A(for instance the pull request that was not accepted), because the only concern is that fork B should have the latest state of repo A to make a pull request of new additions, that's it.

Comment: What are you looking for? A force push or a hard reset?

Comment: Anything may work. The concern is to always have the latest data. Imagine a database.json file in which you are allowing users to add data by PRs. So doesn't matter if your PR was not accepted, you can make another one, but for that the code should make sure that we have the fetched the update file, discarding/force pushing/hard resetting to the latest state same as original repo A

Comment: Git contains enough tools to let you build your desired solution, but does not have this as an existing tool. You can probably build something similar using the GitHub APIs but it will likely be a lot more work.